# Differential Equation with linear variable coefficients - dealing with integration constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem dealing with the constants coming from the integration when solving o.d.e with linear variable coefficients. Specifically we know that for the following differential equation:

$\frac{dy}{dx} + p(x)y = f(x)$

the solution is:

$$(1)$$
$$y=ce^{-\int p(x)dx} + e^{-\int p(x)dx} \int e^{\int p(x)dx}f(x)dx$$

Now let's say we have the following problem:

$\frac{dy}{dx} + tan(x)y = cos^2(x), x \in(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$

We assign $p(x) = tan(x)$ and $f(x)=cos^2(x)$

So:
$$(2)$$
$$I = \int p(x)dx = \int tan(x) dx = -ln(cos(x)) + K$$

Now we substitute (2) into (1). But what we do about the constant K? If we include it, it does not cancel out and then we have two constants, the original c in (1) and the new K. I hope I was clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=ce^{-\int p(x)dx} + e^{-\int p(x)dx} \int e^{\int p(x)dx}f(x)dx$$
$$y=ce^{\ln \cos x -K} + e^{\ln \cos x -K} \int e^K \cos x dx$$
$$y=ce^{-K}{ \cos x} + {\cos x} \int  \cos x dx$$
$$y(x)={C}{ \cos x} +  {\sin x}{\cos x}$$
$$y(x)={C}{ \cos x} + \dfrac 12 {\sin (2x)}$$

You have a unique constant.
$$C=ce^{-K}$$

Comment: Wow. I feel dumb. Thanks.

Comment: No problem you're welcome @ToniIvanov